# DJANGO - Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57565)

Tags: python, django

En una aplicación web con plantilla, bootstrap e imágenes me sale el siguiente error que al utilizar Firefox da el problema, en cambio en Chrome (todo funciona perfecto sin errores):

En Firefox:

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57565)

¿Qué sucede?

Parece que en la lista de errores menciona el **Miniconda**:

```
File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
```

Por consecuencia muestra:

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

Comment: ¿Tienes activado algún firewall o antivirus que esté bloqueando la conexión?

Comment: Creo que no tengo en marcha ningún antivirus ni firewall. Utilizo Windows 10 con firewall desactivado.

Comment: En ese caso, por curiosidad, ¿Miniconda3 es una carpeta que tienes?

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html Debe ser para virtualizar utilizango junti a Python.

Comment: Al utilizar http://127.0.0.1:8000/ en Firefox es cuando da el error 10053 y todos esos errores. Si lo hago en Chrome no da ningún problema, funciona perfecto. (Utilizo Windows 10. ¿Qué sucede con firefox para que de problemas?

Comment: Basado en lo que dices, es probable que alguna extensión esté interrumpiendo la conexión